# Is it possible to change background position by dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

I have a html map that uses world map image as its background.

I can make a js function that changes div's background position, but I like to change background position when user click on the map then drag like google map.

so I have a sample page here: http://lab.qacode.com/map which uses http://lab.qacode.com/map/map.jpg

I would appreciate any advice or tip.

Comment: Ill try writing something right now for ya...

Comment: @Oscar Godson // !! Thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to make this work is to use jQuery UI's [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="map-canvas"></div>    
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Pre-select elements
var map = $("#map"),
    canvas = map.find(".map-canvas");

// Calculate canvas constraints
var maxLeft = map.width()-canvas.width(),
    maxTop = map.height()-canvas.height();

// Make canvas draggable
canvas.draggable({
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        // Check if canvas is within constraints
        if (ui.position.left > 0) {
            ui.position.left = 0;
        } else if (ui.position.left < maxLeft) {
            ui.position.left = maxLeft;
        }
        if (ui.position.top > 0) {
            ui.position.top = 0;
        } else if (ui.position.top < maxTop) {
            ui.position.top = maxTop;
        }
    }
});
```

**Placing markers**

It's possible to place a marker (or whatever) on the map. It's very easy, and the coords are based on pixels within the canvas. For the marker in the test case it's 150px from left and top of canvas.

```
// Create simple dot marker
$("<div></div>")
    .addClass("map-marker")
    .appendTo(canvas)
    .offset(function(){
        return { left: 150, top: 150 };
    })
    // Append a label
    .append("<span><- Dot</span>");
```

Now to something a little more advanced, namely the (in)famous Google Maps pin.

```
// Create draggable Google Maps pin marker
var pin =
$("<div></div>")
    .addClass("google-pin")
    .appendTo(canvas)
    .offset(function(){
        return { left: 50, top: 50 };
    })
    // Bind mouseup/down for visual confirmation of grab
    .bind({
        mousedown: function(){
            var os = pin.offset();
            pin.offset(function(){
                return { top: os.top-3 };
            });
        },
        mouseup: function(){
            var os = pin.offset();
            pin.offset(function(){
                return { top: os.top+3 };
            });
        }
    })
    // Make it draggable
    .draggable({
        start: function(e,ui){
            ui.helper.offset(function(){
                return { top: ui.offset.top-2 };
            });
        },
        container: canvas
    });
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/zd5TJ/)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall // thank you for the script. It works perfectly, but I need to use background image, not an actual img element..

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall // it works perfectly. I really appreciate. But..we already built a fully working map, which uses background position. Is there a way to change background position with jquery?

Comment: @Moon, of course there is. But `draggable` doesn't work with `background-position`. Anyways, I added the containment for you :)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall // thank you for the updated script. I will keep looking and...if I can't find a solution then I will try to adapt your solution. Thanks!!

Comment: @Moon, working with absolute position is better then working with background-position. With fully working map, what exactly do you mean by that? Google Maps is already awesome and very customizable, so no reason to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall // We need a custom design for the whole map. That is why we didn't use google map.

Comment: @Moon, did you really check everything that's possible with Google Maps? There's [custom overlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html) and [custom map styles](http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html). And here's even the [Moon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image.html). Also check out [CloudMade](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall // hahah "here's even the Moon" that part was so funny haha. Thank you Marcus. I really really appreciate. I will checkout those custom map styles tonight.